# El artículo correcto en "llamar (por | a) <número de teléfono>"

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Estoy traduciendo un documento de instrucciones a Español que contiene la frase:

> Please call Alice between 8am-5pm Mon-Fri at (555) 123-4567

Lo he traducido a

> Favor de llamar a Alice 8am-5pm Lunes-Viernes por (555) 123-4567

Pero no estoy seguro del artículo "por" antes del número de teléfono. ¿Se usa "por" o "a" o quizas algo diferente?

Comment: Yo no usaría ninguno de los dos. Usaría "al" o "al número ..." pero por preferencia personal cambiaría el orden así: Favor llamar a Alice al 555-xxxxxxx de lunes a viernes de 8 am a 5 pm (entre las 8 am y las 5 pm).

Comment: Yo prefiero el orden que ya tengo en inglés, pero ¿quizas no es idiomático en español? Hay dos números para llamar dependiente en tiempo y día. En inglés me parece mejor poner los tiempos antes del números.

Comment: Si hay uno o varios números no hay diferencia. Yo igual diría **llamar a Alice al 555 o al 444...**. Si son muchos números **llamar a Alice a cualquiera de estos números/teléfonos 555-xxxx,555-yyyy o 555-zzz de lunes...**

Comment: para las horas: de 0800 a 1700 horas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the context, you could go for a complete sentence, e.g.

> Favor de llamar a Alice de 8 am a 5 pm lunes a viernes, en el (555) 123-4567.

Or you could just list the relevant information, e.g.

> Favor de llamar a Alice, 8am-5pm lunes-viernes, (555) 123-4567

If the number came right after Alice, or right after the verb, "al" would be the right pronoun:

> Favor de llamar al (555) 123-4567

Please note that "a Alice" is awkward because "a" and "Alice" are such a mismatch of vowel sounds.  If you could put another word in between, or rearrange things, it would sound better:

> Favor de llamar al (555) 123-4567 de 8 am a 5 pm, lunes a viernes, ahí le atiende Alice.

*I'd encourage you to check this sort of thing at [linguee.com](http://linguee.com) and then ask if there's something you don't understand.  Basic proofreading of simple translations, without an explanation of what you're confused about, is off topic here.  Normally I'd just vote to close but there was already an answer contributed, which I found confusing, so I didn't want to leave you hanging.*

Comment: Muchas gracias, especialmente el mensaje al fondo. No he usado Español en muchos años y no supe donde podía pedir. Yo leí las reglas pero no ví que mi pregunta no estuvo aceptable. La culpa es mía.

Comment: @AdamSmith - Bienvenido al sitio, no hay cuidado, sólo probando se aprende cómo usar el sitio.  Espero que encuentres cosas interesantes aquí y no dudes en preguntar si topas con algo que no te queda claro (mostrando lo que has probado, claro está).

Comment: @aparente001 Tal vez sea correcto pero a mi me suena terrible decir "Favor **de**" cuando se usa la version corta. Creo que es costumbre pero siempre digo "Favor llamar". Si se usa la frase completa ahí si le pongo el "de". _Haga el favor de llamar a...._ Preferencias personales :-)

Comment: @DGaleano - Bueno, en México por lo menos es bastante común "Favor de etc." pero no me gusta mucho tampoco, preferiría "Llame al 555 etc." Creo que "Favor de" se oye despersonalizado.  ¿Por qué te molesta a tí?

Comment: @aparente001 creo que diste en el clavo con lo de "se oye despersonalizado" Ese es más o menos el sentimiento. "Llame al 555" o "llamar al 555" son la forma imperativa estándar y me suena más _natural_.

Comment: linguee is not a reliable for source for anything. It has tons of mistakes.

Comment: @Lambie - I have found it to be tremendously more helpful than Google Translate.  It offers a wide array of real world usage examples, which one can use as a starting point for understanding usage of a word, phrase or idiom. But it seems you've had a lot of bad experiences with it.  What resource would you suggest  as a starting point for an uncertain Spanish speaker who is required to show what s/he has tried so far?

Comment: Both are terrible. I don't think that everything is on the internet. I am a prof. translator and interpreter, and I think those who know just have to explain it. Then, one can show some example from some well-done Spanish site.....Actually, the OP is an English speaker. I am very fluent in Spanish (and interpret in and out of it) but never do paid written jobs into Spanish....myself.

Comment: @Lambie - I believe you are mistaken about OP, who appears to be a rusty native or bilingual speaker. // To be on topic, a question should show some effort.  OP should consult a dictionary or other resource and if still confused, can then go ahead an ask a question, but should share the attempt(s) made thus far.  If you have a source to suggest for this purpose, that is consistently more useful than linguee.com, by all means please share it here and in our Resources page.

Comment: @aparente001 There's a point where empiricism breaks down. And that's the problem with some of the StackEchange forums. No worries. I explained my philosophy. I think you can illustrate your opinion, by citing some usage on a well-written site, but not everything can be "proved". There is no site that does this. There may be sites that may contain examples of what a person answering a question believes to be good grammar, for example. That yes.

Comment: @Lambie - If you want to discuss how things are done on this or other SE sites, Meta is a good place for that. // *Empiricism breaks down* -- I have no idea what empiricism has to do with this. // Similarly I don't know why you're talking about proving something. // What I'm asking you is, for OP to demonstrate having put in some effort, where would you suggest s/he do that?  Given that you have such a serious objection to the resource I suggested?

Comment: I don't want to discuss how things are done. I am saying some things can only be shown by knowing them, not by proving them.

Comment: @Lambie - What OP is supposed to show is not the solution, not knowledge.  OP is supposed to show what they've tried and where they got stuck.

Comment: @aparente001 I was not referring to ***the*** OP, I was referring to those who give answers. Please just let me have my opinion. Thanks.

Comment: Of course, @Lambie, you're welcome to hate linguee if you want to, and I apologize if I defended it too strenuously. I got a new idea about the snowflake question from it just today.  Shall we agree to disagree?

Answer (score -1):

"at" se traduce a "a", "al" o "en"; muy rara vez (o nunca) he visto que "at" se traduzca a "por".

En cuyo caso debes usar la preposición más apropiada, en este caso "al" o "a".

Indicar qué preposiciones se deben usar en cada caso es un tema más complicado. En este caso, podemos indicar que "a" y "al" indican una dirección a una ubicación específica, mientras que "por" indica una aproximación.

Tampoco se usa "en" porque "en" no indica dirección, sino la localización misma.

La traducción más correcta sería:

Por favor llamar a Alice entre las 8 am y 5 pm de lunes a viernes al (555) ...